# Select2 in search form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I need to build a search form with Select2 but I have problems getting it to work right.

The user enters the search term into the field which populates suggestions via AJAX. A click on the suggestions brings him to the page. Otherwise he needs to click on the submit button / or press enter, to get to the extended search. The last point (click on the submit button) doesn't work.

```
<form action="/search" method="get" class="form-search" id="global_search_form">
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" name="q" class="search-query" id="global_search" placeholder="Enter search term ...">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#global_search").select2({
    placeholder:        "Enter search term ...",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    multiple:           1,
    containerCssClass: 'search-query',
    ajax: {
        url:        'remoteGlobalSearch',
        dataType:   'jsonp',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q:          term,
                per_page:   10,
                page:       page
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            var more = (page * 10) < data.total;

            return {
                results:    data.items,
                more:       more
            };
        }
    },
    formatResult:       itemFormatResult,
    formatSelection:    itemFormatSelection,
    escapeMarkup:       function (m) {
        return m;
    }
});

function itemFormatResult(item) {
    var markup = '<table class="item-result"><tr>';

    if (item.image !== undefined) {
        markup += '<td class="item-image"><img src="' + item.image + '" /></td>';
    }

    markup += '<td class="item-info"><div class="item-type">' + item.type_string + '</div>';
    markup += '<div class="item-title">' + item.title + '</div>';
    markup += '<div class="item-description">' + item.description + '</div>';
    markup += '</td></tr></table>';

    return markup;
}

function itemFormatSelection(item) {
    location.href = item.url;
}
</script>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a compatibility issue with `button`, `type=submit` and how various browsers interpret it.
Have you tried to use

```
<input type="submit" value="Search">
```

instead of the button tag?

Or, if you really need to use the button tag, then I would recommend having something as:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="this.form.submit()">Search</button>
```

Did this solve your problem?
Cheers!

Comment: Hey Radu, thank you for your reply. Changing the submit button doesn't show any effect. The main problem is, that the select2 search field loses his value on blur.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood initially your question. But now I got it. You could try to either use a custom tokenizer for select2 that onblur would tokenize user input, either add a "onkeyup" event for the global_search field that will populate a hidden field with the current value. Then you should get what you want.